# 2D Array, program crash

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Here's a piece of code coming from a C# project using a 2d array. For a reason I don't understand my program compiles perfectly but during run-time it crashes.

```
public class Tile_Info
{
  public int id;

  public Tile_Info(int _id)
  {
    id = _id;
  }
}

class Program
{

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int width = 20;
    int height = 30;

    Tile_Info[,] my_tile;
    my_tile = new Tile_Info[width, height];

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
      for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      {
        my_tile[x, y].id = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the debugger it's because "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", but I'm pretty sure it's what I'm doing here: `my_tile = new Tile_Info[width, height];`.

Anyone can tell what's wrong? Thank you for your support!

Comment: btw: try to use debugger to find such errors!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The creation of the array does not create the objects themselves, just like a creation of a parking lot does not create the cars that park there.

You still need to create the objects yourself. Change

```
my_tile[x, y].id = 0;
```

to

```
my_tile[x, y] = new Tile_Info(0);
```

This only happens when reference types (`class`) are used because the thing that is stored in the array is a reference to an instance, instead of the instance itself. On a lower level this (more or less) means that the memory for the instance is not yet allocated, just the memory for its reference, so you must `new` up an instance to initialize it. On the other hand if `Tile_Info` is a value type (`struct`) then the array will contain the actual instance, and the `new Tile_Info[width, height]`  would have initialized the allocated memory to valid start state (all zeroes), which is exactly what the default parameterless constructor of a value type does.

So, if you had defined Tile_Info like this:

```
public struct Tile_Info
{
  public int id; // this should be a property, public fields are baaad
  public Tile_Info(int _id){ id = _id;}
}
```

both `my_tile[x, y].id = 0` and `my_tile[x, y] = new Tile_Info(0)` would have been legal.

Comment: Thank you very much you solved my problem, I was certain the object was automatically created. At least when I used the 'int' or 'string' type the object seemed to be already created.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to show why that is. Basically it's a "reference type vs value type" thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new 2D Tile_Info array by the first new keyword.

You have only created an empty array that can hold items of type Tile_Info. Its your job to create individual items and put them in the array.